# Thread Windows Phone App 8.1 RunTime

Tags: multithreading, windows-runtime

I have a method to get data JSON like this?

```
 async public void MethodName()
{...response = await postStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();}
```

Now I want use a thread to Run Implicit this function.

How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the thread pool to submit a work item.

[Quickstart: Submitting a work item to the thread pool (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj248677.aspx)

Comment: please clearly in your answer, I dont understand, I just have a method like this. Now What thing i do it ?

Comment: if you want to start a new thread to this method, you just need the define public async void MethodName and call it with MethodName() with out await, .NET will start a new thread for in Threadpool implicitly because it is async method. To start a new thread explicitly,  you can submit a new work item, please check the document in my last post.